# Check which Controls have Borders c#

Tags: c#, controls, border

I am making a Winforms application. Because I want to redraw some borders I want to loop through the controls and check which controls have a border. Unfortunately I have no idea how to accomplish this.

I know panels and textboxes, etc. have a property BorderStyle but I can not access it while looping through Controls. I use the function from this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=netframework-4.8 , to loop through the controls.

Comment: If you can't decide on which types of controls you have you can uzse reflection to find out if they have a BorderStyle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a panel you can foreach on the panel. I use form load as an event

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in this.Controls)
        {
            switch (item.GetType().Name)
            {
                case "Label":
                    if (((Label)item).BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None)
                    {
                        //Your commands
                    }
                break;
                case "TextBox":
                    if (((TextBox)item).BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None)
                    {
                        //Your commands
                    }
               break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Or you can check them dynamic

**I recommend you to use the dynamic way.**

in this way, your app wouldn't encounter exceptions or errors

```
        foreach (var item in this.Controls)
        {
            //Get item from form
            dynamic element = item;
            //check if there is any property called Borderstyle exists
            var res = item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.Equals("BorderStyle")).FirstOrDefault();
            //if it exists and value is not equal None(Control have border)
            if (res !=null && !(res.GetValue(item).Equals("None")))
            {
            res.SetValue(item, BorderStyle.FixedSingle, null);
            //your other commands
            }
        }
```

Comment: The dynamic way should work ! The switch idea is something i would like to avoid since i have a lot of custom controls so everytime i add a new control I should add this in the switch.

Comment: @YLohrmnn Yes, i personally prefer a dynamic way. switch it's for some cases that your commands are based on your control types.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach for every type of control you use (TextBox, Label, etc.)

```
var controlsWithoutBorders = new List<Control>();

// Check textboxes
foreach (var control in controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    if (control.BorderStyle != BorderStyle.None)
    {
        controlsWithoutBorders.Add(control);
    }
}

//Check labels
foreach (var control in controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    if (control.BorderStyle != BorderStyle.None)
    {
        controlsWithoutBorders.Add(control);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a single `foreach` on all the controls, and try to cast the control to each type. The cast will be successful if the control is actually what you want to cast it to, otherwise it will return null (e.g. trying to cast a `Control` that is a `TextBox` to a `Label` will return `null`)

```
var controlsWithoutBorders = new List<Control>();

foreach (var control in controls)
{
    var controlAsTextBox = control as TextBox;
    var controlAsLabel = control as Label;

    if (controlAsTextBox != null && controlAsTextBox.BorderStyle != BorderStyle.None)
    {
        controlsWithBorders.Add(control);
    }

    if (controlAsLabel != null && controlAsLabel.BorderStyle != BorderStyle.None)
    {
        controlsWithBorders.Add(control);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this method is not the fastest at run time, your problem could be cleanly solved with the use of C#'s dynamic typing feature. Consider the below snippet of code.

```
   public void DealWithBorder(List<Control> lsControls) {
        foreach(var element in lsControls){
            dynamic dynamicElement = element;
            try{
                BorderStyle style = dynamicElement.BorderStyle;
                // Handle if property does exist in the control
            }
            catch{
                // Handle if property doesnt exist in the control
            }
        }
    }
```

In English, it will try to act as if the property exists in the object but if it does not, an exception will thrown. For more info on dynamic typing, click [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dynamic-type).

Comment: @TaW Could you explain why? (If I had to guess, it would be the overhead involved )

Comment: Yes. Exceptions are expensive and should catch the unexpected only.